# NodeJs: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I'm creating a simple valid login check in the route with validating jwt token

In the route:

```
router.post("/contacts", async function (req, res, next) {
  await checkLogin(req, res, next);
  res.send(userController.getContacts());
});

async function checkLogin(req, res, next) {
  const loggedIn = await userController.isLoggedIn(req);
  if (!loggedIn) {
    res.status(401).json({ error: "You are not authorized" });
  }
}
```

In the controller

```
async function isLoggedIn(req) {
  let token = req.header("authorization");
  if (!token) {
    return false;
  }
  token = token.substring(7); //remove Bearer from the beginning
  return jwt.verify(token, tokenSecret, function (err, decoded) {
    if (typeof decoded == "object" && decoded.email == req.body.email) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

It's working fine with valid and invalid token but with invalid token I get this log

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

If I remove `status(401)` this error log doesn't show up. Why does it happen and how to set HTTP STATUS to 401 without triggering this error log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `checkLogin`, which sets a status code and replies to the request. After `checkLogin` finishes, the response has already been sent, and you can't send a *second* response.

What you're missing is some conditional logic that would abort processing in case the user is not logged in. Usually, this is implemented in *middlewares* - a middleware can intercept the request before it reaches the handler.

I can see that your `checkLogin` implementation already looks a bit like a middleware function: it accepts a `next` argument. You can turn it into one like this:

```js
async function checkLogin(req, res, next) {
  const loggedIn = await userController.isLoggedIn(req);
  if (!loggedIn) {
    res.status(401).json({ error: "You are not authorized" });
    return;
  }
  next();
}
router.post("/contacts", checkLogin, function (req, res, next) {
  res.send(userController.getContacts());
});
```

This tells express.js to evaluate `checkLogin` middleware first, and only pass control to the handler when the middleware calls `next()`. If it never calls next - control is never passed, so the "main logic" for authenticated users will never run.

Read more about middlewares here: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#middleware-callback-function-examples

Comment: Note that I had to edit the answer, because it was missing a "return" in the conditional block in checkLogin. Don't miss it!

Answer (score 0):

You are sending 401 if user is not logged-in in `checkLogin`, but this method was called in your `router.post`, so it would run the next statement in the route handler which is `res.send();`. But since you have already sent 401 status, node is complaining here that it has already replied to the client and you are trying to send another reply.

You need to have both `res` in your route handler.

```
router.post("/contacts", async function (req, res, next) {
  let loggedIn = checkLogin(req, res, next);
  if (!loggedIn) {
    res.status(401).json({ error: "You are not authorized" });
  } else {
    res.send(userController.getContacts());
  }
});

async function checkLogin(req, res, next) {
    return await userController.isLoggedIn(req);
}
```

This should fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

In case when user is not logged in the application tried to send 2 responses which is why the error is coming.

1st response :

```
async function checkLogin(req, res, next) {
  const loggedIn = await userController.isLoggedIn(req);
  if (!loggedIn) {
    res.status(401).json({ error: "You are not authorized" });
  }
}
```

when loggedIn is false res.status().json() will send a response to user.

2nd response
Now code returns to the line where the above function was called because there is no return statement to stop/skip the execution

```
router.post("/contacts", async function (req, res, next) {
  await checkLogin(req, res, next);
  res.send(userController.getContacts());
});
```

so after `await checkLogin(req, res, next);`, `res.send(userController.getContacts());`
is called which means that for one call your code is trying to send 2 responses.